# Tagging confusion/inconsistency with alloy-ui

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-synonyms, ambiguous-tags, tag-autocomplete

I've noticed that many questions tagged as [alloy-ui](/questions/tagged/alloy-ui), are incorrectly tagged. Namely, topics involving [Appcelerator's Alloy framework for the Titanium SDK](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/alloy/). While [Alloy UI](http://alloyui.com/) is a javascript framework which is built upon the [yui3](/questions/tagged/yui3) and used extensively within [liferay](/questions/tagged/liferay).

I'd suggest:

1. Creating/updating synonyms for; [titanium-alloy](/questions/tagged/titanium-alloy). For example: [alloy-for-titanium](/questions/tagged/alloy-for-titanium), [alloy-titanium](/questions/tagged/alloy-titanium), [appcelerator-alloy](/questions/tagged/appcelerator-alloy), [alloy-appcelerator](/questions/tagged/alloy-appcelerator), [alloy-mvc](/questions/tagged/alloy-mvc), [titanium-mvc](/questions/tagged/titanium-mvc).
2. Retagging topics related to Alloy for Titanium, to a more accurate, [alloy-for-titanium](/questions/tagged/alloy-for-titanium) or [alloy-titanium](/questions/tagged/alloy-titanium)

I've attempted to re-tag these questions with moderate success. But was stopped by some who felt my edits were:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

I feel that accurate tagging is not minor or non-substantive, and is critical to Stack Overflow. It allows experts to easily identify questions in their respective domains.

I'll admit my edits did not cover 'multiple issues in the post', but I did not feel comfortable altering the original questions, as I am not an expert in the, Alloy for Titanium, domain.

I'd like to come to a consensus, on whether these proposals help or hinder these [alloy-ui](/questions/tagged/alloy-ui) questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think I have a problem. Only 2 [tag:titanium-alloy] users (@JosiahHester, @AaronSaunders) are close, but not quite, to having enough rep and/or tag score to even suggest/vote on [tag:titanium-alloy] synonyms.

Comment: @JosiahHester: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:874257+[titanium-alloy]

Comment: @AaronSaunders: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:122313+[titanium-alloy]

Answer (score 3):

I just tried to retag the incorrect alloy-ui tags referencing the Titanium framework. Some were accepted and some rejected because the edit is too minor. (Someone also pointed out that I'm just a *"d**bag making unnecessary edits"*). Finally [Flexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) kindly pointed me to this thread.

I agree with you in that having proper tagging is more than just a silly whim. Currently, the knowledge base StackOverflow has about alloy-ui and titanium-alloy is very confusing. People that come looking for any information about them will be confused and questions may not reach the proper experts in the field.

If just editing the incorrect tag is not worth it, and as Byran says, one may not be knowledgeable enough to add more value to the question (again, if you ask me, proper categorization is not so trivial). What's the proper way, if any, to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm strongly in favour of correct tagging. The usual course of action for bulk changes is to seek consensus here on meta and then act based on that consensus. (This question has had rather low traffic since it was asked). Once there's an agreement emerging you can point to this post in the edit which usually helps make sure that reviewers and others are aware of the background to the edits.

Comment: @Flexo Thanks! What are the *rules* about agreement? Is lazy consensus enough? If no-one opposes and some positive votes are casted, can one assume consensus is reached or is some more explicit consensus needed?

Comment: There are no hard and fast rules. Generally someone says "I think we should do X, Y, Z" to fix the problem and nobody disagrees after a reasonable period. (Currently it's not clear to me if you're changing all [tag:alloy-ui] questions or being more selective, if you're editing all of them then a synonym is probably more appropriate. Also when your edits have to be reviewed make sure they cover all the issues in the post, not just the tags)

Comment: [AlloyUI](http://alloyui.com/) and [Alloy Framework](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework) are two unrelated projects. I was only editing the questions tagged as [alloy-ui](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/alloy-ui/info) that referred to [titanium-alloy](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/titanium-alloy/info) instead. As you suggest, I'll wait to see if someone raises any objections, and try again adding the proper background and context to the edits. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Flexo for the tip to link edits to this this thread. I'll edit my post to be more clear about my goals.

Comment: @Jbalsas It's a shame that moderator felt the need to use terms like that, while rejecting an edit. He could have been far more civil and provide constructive input.

Comment: @Byran Anyone with 2000 reputation can review an edit. It's probably not a (diamond) moderator who added that inappropriate comment.

Comment: IMO fixing tags on questions should be just as valued as actual answers to questions (especially when fixing tags for good/accepted answers). Otherwise, people might just re-ask the same question and waste everyone's time.